# python: drawing images and plots in the same figure

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I want to draw on the same figure a set of images and a plot under each of them. I'm using the ImageGrid module. It results to be good for images alone, but when I mix them with others plot I obtain axes scaled in different ways

```
n_rows = 2
n_cols = 4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
fig  = plotter.figure(figsize=(3*n_rows,3*n_cols))
axes = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                         nrows_ncols=(n_rows, n_cols),
                         axes_pad=0.4,
                         label_mode="1",
                         share_all=False,
                         )
import numpy

img = numpy.random.rand(224,224,3)
bars= numpy.random.rand(10,)
axes[0].imshow(img)
axes[1].imshow(img)
axes[2].imshow(img)
axes[3].imshow(img)
axes[4].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[5].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[6].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[7].bar(range(0,10), bars)
plotter.show()
```

I obtain:

[image: code output]

As you can see, the barplots are very small, instead I would that the plots are of the same size of the images without changing the bar values (they are very small) and with the bar equally spaced between them.

Furthermore, the result seems to be strongly influenced on the figure dimensions and on the number of the images to draw, and I need a general solution because the number of images is variable.

I also tried using the classic `subplots` function with similar results.

```
_,axes = plotter.subplots(4,4)
axes[0][0].imshow(img)
axes[0][1].imshow(img)
axes[0][2].imshow(img)
axes[0][3].imshow(img)
axes[1][0].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[1][1].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[1][2].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[1][3].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[2][0].imshow(img)
axes[2][1].imshow(img)
axes[2][2].imshow(img)
axes[2][3].imshow(img)
axes[3][0].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[3][1].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[3][2].bar(range(0,10), bars)
axes[3][3].bar(range(0,10), bars)
```

where the output is:

[[image: second attempt output2]

However, the plots and images have different sizes and the bar plots results to be smaller if its values are smaller, instead I would them to be of the same dimensions of the images.

Is there a simple solution to have all the images and plots "visibles" on the same figure and of the same dimensions without that some process make them too small or too large?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not important for the images to look square, you can set `imshow(..., aspect='auto')`. That way, the image plots will occupy their complete sub-area. Without `aspect='auto'`, the images are forced to look squared, and either their width or their height will be reduced to fit into their sub-area.

```py
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_rows = 6
n_cols = 4

fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(3 * n_cols, 3 * n_rows))

img = numpy.random.rand(224, 224, 3)
bars = numpy.random.rand(10, )

for i in range(0, n_rows, 2):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        axes[i, j].imshow(img, aspect='auto')
        axes[i + 1, j].bar(range(0, 10), bars)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: test plot]

Comment: It looks smaller if I add more rows. Furthermore, it does not work with imagegrid...

Comment: `ImageGrid` is only meant for images. It adapts the grid dividers also for images that all have different sizes. It doesn't work well with other type of plots. Which problem do you encounter with `plt.subplots()`?

Comment: using subplots, I have that the barplots are "stretched" on the X axis. I would that they have same size of the images

Comment: However, in your code there is the solution: `figsize=(3 * n_cols, 3 * n_rows)`. so first the columns and then the rows.

Comment: Yes, figsize is `(width, height)`. When doubting, just change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my error (with `.subplots`) is in the figure dimensions:
`figsize=(3*n_rows,3*n_cols)`
figsize wants the width as first argument, and height as second argument, so
`figsize=(3*n_cols,3*n_rows)`, differently from `.subplots` where the first argument is the number of rows and the second argument is number of columns.